# Creating a new date field by splitting an existing timestamp in Kibana 5.0.0

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack, kibana-5

I already have an index which contains data from a MySQL database and I wanted use `Histogram` aggregation Kibana so that I can show a `vertical bar chart` or a `data table` for every single day.

The problem I'm having is that, I don't particularly have, a day or a month or an year field in my db separately. What I have is a `timestamp` field in my table, like as follows:

[image]

How can i create a scripted field or is there any other way in `Kibana` to get only the day, month and the year from the `timestamp` so that I can include it in the `histogram`.

Any help could be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create the visualization, just set the Interval to Daily.  This will summarize the data by day instead of auto-selecting the bar size.